# DOM2 events in mobile browsers?

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom, browser

I am currently developping a HTML/Javascript mobile application, and my question is :
are DOM2 addEventListener(...) functions compatible with mobile browsers/which ones?

PS couldn't find the answer on http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser compatibility on MDN states effectively all mobile browsers support this:

```
Android  Firefox Mobile (Gecko) IE Mobile   Opera Mobile    Safari Mobile
1.0      1.0 (1.0)              9.0         6.0             1.0
```

Looking at that table and [IE Mobile versioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_Mobile#Version_9), my guess would be only Windows Phone 7.0 users who haven't updated since day 1 (of which there are probably about 3) probably don't have this functionality. Safe to assume that you can use it for mobile development.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `addEventListener` will be available in any sort of modernish browser, with the exception of some of the older Microsoft based devices.

That has been an implemented standard for at least a decade now.